# MySQL create and/or update child table rows from header parent row for standing orders

Tags: mysql

I am writing a system to manage income and expenses using MySQL but it needs to be able to handle standing orders i.e. incomes or expenses which repeat monthly, quarterly or yearly.

Also, ideally I would trigger a query to delete child rows if the associated header row is deleted.

So I have a table with a name, start and end date, payment frequency (M/A) and I need to output all the payment dates between start and end given the frequency (M)onthly or (A)nnual using a MySQL procedure.

My header table say **sorders_head** would be of the form

```
id, 1
name, Council Tax
payment, £300
start_date, 05/04/2018
end_date, 05/01/2019
frequency, M
```

My line table say **sorders_line** would need to create the following rows

```
id
sorders_head_id, key to header table id 
payment_date
payment
```

The output of the sorders_line table should be as follows :-

```
1,1,05/04/2018,£300
2,1,05/05/2018,£300
3,1,05/06/2018,£300
etc. ending
10,1,05/01/2019,£300
```

I have been trying to find examples of a MySQL procedure which will process 2 dates in this way using MySQL, I will continue looking, any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

I have written the following procedure which does what I want except for being generic for frequency, , which I will work on now ..

```
BEGIN

DECLARE currDate DATE;
DECLARE endDate DATE;

SELECT *, 
       @currDate := min(DATE_FORMAT(sh.date_from, "%Y-%m-01")), 
       @endDate := max(DATE_FORMAT(sh.date_to, "%Y-%m-01"))
  FROM
  sorders_head sh
  WHERE
  code = 'PENS-TEST';

SET currDate = @currDate;
SET endDate = @endDate;



REPEAT

-- execute your queries for every frequency say MONTH
SELECT currDate;

-- ADD INSERT COMMANDS HERE
INSERT INTO sorders_line(code, name, type, paydate, amount, member_id, account_id, sorders_head_id) 
SELECT code, name, type, `currDate`, amount, '1', '6', id 
FROM sorders_head 
WHERE 
code = 'PENS-TEST';

-- ADD INSERT COMMANDS HERE




SET currDate = DATE_ADD(currDate,INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
UNTIL currDate > endDate 



END REPEAT;

END
```

This successfully inserts rows into the sorders_line table

```
currDate
2012-09-20

currDate
2012-10-20

currDate
2012-11-20

currDate
2012-12-20

currDate
2013-01-20
```

etc. ......

This now works, I just need to work out the following :-

1/ the procedure should work for different frequency types e.g. (M or A)

2/ create a trigger to call the procedure for each INSERT of an sorders_head row
3/ use the current sorders_head.code value in the WHERE clause shown above

4/ integrate into my wpDataTables if possible.

Colin

Comment: Use a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` to automatically delete the child rows when the parent is deleted.

Comment: Thanks Barmer, I am relatively new to SQL query so I was unaware of this construct, great tip. Colin